# How can I enable UML support in PyCharm 5

Tags: python, plugins, ide, uml, pycharm

In the PyCharm documentation I found [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/working-with-diagrams.html) section about generating UML diagrams. It tells me, that as a prerequisite I need to enable the `UML Support` plugin (which should be installed and enabled by default).

There is no such plugin installed and it is not in the standard repository under `File->Settings->Plugins`. How can I get this plugin and make diagrams work?

Maybe I should note that the mentioned section of the documentation also appears in the help file installed with PyCharm 5.0 and that the same issue occurs with PyCharm 4.5, so I would expect that this feature has not been removed recently.

Comment: Are you using the Community Edition?

Comment: @PeterWood Yes I do. This explains everything. Thank you very much!